# How can I "pull" a git database without downloading the whole repository

Tags: git, repository, git-pull

I have the *content* of a huge project (with some changes) but not the Git database. One could get to the same situation for example like this:

1. `git clone <...>/repo.git`
2. `cd repo`
3. `echo "Blah" > new_file.txt`
4. `rm .git`

Since my repo is huge and all the project files are still there, I do not want to re-clone everything. How can I get back to a normal situation, where I would be able to commit and push my `new_file.txt`?

I tried searching in general and among other questions here but nothing seems to provide the answer for this specific situation.

Comment: [Shallow](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) clone?

Comment: Do you know which "branch" you would be committing to? Do you know how far you've diverged from the git repository? Are you the only one working on it? Depending on what you want to do and how the git repo has progressed, you might be facing a few issues here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: If I understand correctly, shallow cloning downloads only part of the history. If so, that would be the dual of what I want: I want to download _all_ history but _no_ code (I have the code already)

Comment: @zrrbite: Yes, I know the branch (in my concrete case, there is only one!). There are other people working on the repo/branch and I know that the two have diverged somewhat but _I also know that there are no conflicts_ (we are working on disjoint sets of files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clone the repository using `git clone --no-checkout` into another directory, say `dir`.
2. Copy `dir/.git` to your repo.
3. Go to your repo and run `git reset`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @fmontesi. The problem here is that this would clone the entire repository _with the project files_, which I want to avoid because there is too much data to download.

Comment: Forgot to mention the magical flag: `git clone --no-checkout`. It might do the trick. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Ah-ha, managed to try it out on the tablet.

 1. Clone the repository using `git clone --no-checkout` into another directory.
 2. Copy `.git` to your repo.
 3. Run `git reset`.

Done. :-)

Comment: Excellent, thanks @fmontesi! Works like a charm. I added steps 4 & 5 showing how to catch up with the commits made remotely but not locally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.git` folder which contains the database. You could compress that into a *zip* file, download it and copy it into your folder. So, the steps:

1. Navigate to the folder in the repository
2. Compress the `.git` folder
3. Download it
4. Uncompress it into your folder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @lajos-arpad and @swisscodemen, this makes a lot of sense! One problem: my remote is on GitLab and I can't find `.git` there (not to mention an option to compress it)

Comment: @SimonBliudze Then you might want to issue git init and then add the remote as a new remote: https://articles.assembla.com/en/articles/1136998-how-to-add-a-new-remote-to-your-git-repo